# How to create a preview within a browser (browser within a browser with predefined contents)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering how I would go about creating a 'preview' of a page within a browser. That acts as a browser itself. I might not be explaining it very well. I mean something like what is done on www.bootstrapbay.com when you click to 'live demo' the themes. I would like to do something similiar but couldn't seem to find any tutorials.

What I am really asking is if anyone can point me in the right direction in terms of documentation of the correct phrase to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On www.bootstrapbay.com , they are using a **canvas** designed to look like a browser ... If you want a webpage preview within a webpage, this can be done using an **Iframe** .

**Example.**

```
<iframe src="http://www.bootstrapbay.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

better example : 
http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/MewpMy

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link too :D

Answer (score 2):

It's just an iframe. Have a look at the source code, bootstrapbay just place an iframe where they want the 'preview' you're looking for to display.

```
<iframe id="preview" height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%" src="http://bootstrapstarterkit.com/bskit-demo/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Dan :D